# android-Specifying authentication between user and admin

Tags: android, authentication

I'm writing an android application which will have two types of users.One is admin that s gonna make adding and removing needed stuff and user that is gonna just read only.And I dont know a word about how can i make authentication between them.I need some source and advice.So if I can hear some advice.I really become so happy :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do this with the help of SharedPreference!!

Answer (score 0):

There would be several approaches to this. One rather quick that gives some flexibility would be to:

1) Create an:
interface ApplicationRights {

boolean writeX()

boolean canSeeButtonY()

}

Then you have a static variable of ApplicationRights interface somewhere accessible from anywhere in the application. (there would be many options for this, this is just a simple way)

To complement this you have two classes:

class AdminRights implements ApplicationRights {
...
}

and

class UserRights implements ApplicationRights {
...
}

Then in that static variable, as soon as you know if it's a User or Admin you
create and put either the UserRights or AdminRights in there. Doing so will allow you to customise this behaviour on a more finegrained level.

And whenever you add a new piece of code that will differ from a User and Admin you can easily add another boolean method in the interface to decide upon the rights. (This would also easily allow you to create more roles than users and admins)

Then to decide and save this to repeat it you can use for example SharedPreferences for knowing which user to create.

Comment: this might be a long process. checking the login status with sharedpreference may be better.

Comment: Thanks for your concern.I will think about it.